# How to get the values within a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am having the following code

```
var s = Request.Cookies["myvalue"].Value;
string[] values = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Here is the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddToCart").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
        if (typeof $.cookie('myvalue') == 'undefined') {
            $.cookie("myvalue", 0, { expiry: 1 });
        }            
        var a = $(".img1").attr("id");          
        var imgsrc = $.cookie("myvalue").split(",");
        var count = 0;
        var totalitems = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc.length; i++) {                             
            if (a == imgsrc[i]) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        var lenghtOfArry = imgsrc.length;
        if (count >= lenghtOfArry) {
            $.cookie("myvalue", $.cookie("myvalue") + "," + a, { expiry: 10 });
        }
        else {
            alert('This value already exist');
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc.length; i++) {
            totalitems++;
        }
        $(".para").text("CART" + " " + "(" + totalitems + ")");
        $(".para").css("color", "#fff");
        $(".para").css("text-align", "center");
    });
});
```

When I try to access the cookie value while debugging its giving the value as

```
0%2C40%2C50%2C60%2C80%2C9
```

I want the values to be as

```
0 4 5 6 8 9
```

How to do it?

Comment: Did you explicitly Url-encoded the value before dumping the cookie?

Comment: If question isn't clear plz comment

Comment: Can you show how you write values to the cookie?

Comment: try this :
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];


if (myCookie != null)
   string values  =myCookie.Value;
string[] values = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie value seems to be url encoded. Try the following:

```
var s = Request.Cookies["myvalue"].Value;
s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s ?? string.Empty);
string[] values = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
```